# How can I add 'androidx/datastore/preferences/core/PreferencesKeys' to my Xamarin.Android project

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, binding

I'm working with Xmarin.Forms and needed to consume some native 3rd parties into my project. I've managed to create the binding projects and go through the setup with minimal problems. The 3rd party libraries have been developed using Androidx so I had to migrate my Xamarin.Android project to Anroidx too. I'm abble to run the project and open the app but it seems the library is looking to use Landroidx/datastore/preferences/core/PreferencesKeys and it can't find it so it's throwing the following error:

Failed resolution of: Landroidx/datastore/preferences/core/PreferencesKeys;

How can I add this library into my Xamarin.Android project?

Any help would be much appreciated.

I thought about creating another binding project but had no success so far.
Looked for the nuget package but can't find it.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be bound, at least not when looking here https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidX/tree/main/source

Answer (score 0):

The `androidx/datastore/preferences/core/PreferencesKeys` belongs to the Nuget package named [Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.AndroidX.Preference/). You can download the Nuget Package for the support.

Comment: This package is already included in the solution but it didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: You can rebuild the project and try to run it again.